# Доступ к HDFS файлам со всех компьютеров кластера

Tags: solaris, unix, map-reduce, java, linux

Моя `hadoop` программа первоначально запускалась в локальном режиме, а теперь моей целью стало запуск в полностью распределенном режиме.

Для этого необходимо обеспечить доступ к файлам, чтение которых выполняется в  функциях reducer и mapper, со всех компьютеров кластера и поэтому я [задал вопрос](http://answers.mapr.com/questions/4444/syntax-of-option-files-in-hadoop-script) - также поскольку неизвестно на каком компьютере будет выполняться функция mapper (mapper из логики программы будет только один и программа будет запускаться только с одним mapper), то необходимо обеспечить также доступ на всем кластере к файлу, поступающему на вход  функции mapper.

В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос: Можно ли непосредственно использовать hdfs-файлы, то есть скопировать предварительно файлы из файловой системы Linux в файловую систему HDFS (тем самым как я предполагаю, эти файлы станут доступными на всех компьютерах кластера, если это не так, то поправьте пожалуйста) и затем использовать HDFS Java API для чтения этих файлов, в функциях reducer и mapper, выполняющихся на компьютерах кластера?

Если на этот вопрос ответ положительный, то приведите пожалуйста пример копирования из файловой системы Linux в файловую систему HDFS и чтения этих файлов в java программе с помощью HDFS Java API.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS - это по сути своей все еще файловая система (хоть и распределенная). Соответственно в нее можно скопировать любые файлы из локальной файловой системы.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();    
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

Path localPath = new Path("/home/user/file");
Path hdfsPath = new Path("/user/hadoop/file");
fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath,  hdfsPath);
```

Comment: @a_gura я, во-первых, хочу уточнить, вы наверно хотели написать во второй строке

    FileSystem hdfs=FileSystem.get(conf)
во-вторых, я хотел спросить будут ли `hdfs`-файлы доступны на всех компьютерах кластера, и, в-третьих, также очень нужно знать как осуществить чтение содержимого `hdfs`-файла и запсиь этого содержимого в `java` строку.

Comment: @ivan31 Нет, я написал то, что хотел. Да, файлы будут доступны. 
Что вы подразумеваете под hdfs-файлом?

Comment: @a_gura насчет уточнения - в книге Чака Лема Hadoop в действии было именно


    FileSystem hdfs=FileSystem.get(conf)
    FileSystem local=FileSystem.get(conf)
поэтому я и уточнил. А по поводу hdfs-файла - я просто в этой же книге видел следующие строки кода

    Path hdfsFile=new Path(args[1])
    FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile)
Как я понимаю для чтения всего содержимого `hdfs`-файла надо завести переменную

    FSDataInputStream in = hdfs.create(hdfsFile)
но что дальше делать для чтения `hdfs`-файла и записи всего его содержимого в `java` строку я не представляю.

Comment: @ivan31 У вас уже есть InputStream. Просто читайте из него как из обычного файла. Читайте руководство по Java IO (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Comment: @a_gura а копирование файла из hdfs осуществляется с помощью функции

    fs.copyToLocalFile(hdfsPath, localPath)
?

Comment: раз 5 посмотрел на

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

и на 

    FileSystem hdfs=FileSystem.get(conf);

извините, а в чем разница?